# CSS - Sidebar height won't expand

Tags: css, wordpress

I'[m a newbie and not sure how to solve this CSS problem (or what I think is caused by the CSS).  My sidebar height will not expand to include all the content:http://soundcues.net/wordpress/edu-discount/

The content does take a moment to load so this may also be why the height loads at the incorrect size?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div.sidebar-wrapper.span4 {` is set to "position:absolute" remove that and it will work.